# Django Template how to apply filter on the result returned by simple tag

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have a following simple_tag.

```
@register.simple_tag
def Test(arg1,arg2)
   return arg1+arg2
```

And in the template.

```
 <h6>{% Test val.arg1 val.arg2 %}</h6>
```

And now I want to apply the filter on the above `returned` data from `simple_tag` Test,

for example, I want to apply `naturaltime` filter on the returned data, how to do it along with the simple tag.

```
<h6>{% Test val.arg1 val.arg2 | naturaltime %}</h6>
```

Comment: What about `{% Test val.arg1 val.arg2 as result %}{{ result|naturaltime }}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a *simple tag*, you can store the result of a template tag in a variable with the `as` keyword, as is specified in the [documentation on *simple tags*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

> It’s possible to store the **tag results in a template variable**
>   rather than directly outputting it. This is done by using the `as`
>   argument followed by the variable name. Doing so enables you to output
>   the content yourself where you see fit:
>
> ```
> {% current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
> <p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
> ```

So in this case we can render the output with:

```
<h6>{% Test val.arg1 val.arg2 as result %}{{ result|naturaltime }}</h6>
```